# cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type NAType not supported

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

I am trying to insert data into an oracle table, while in the process I am getting this error:

```
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type NAType not supported
```

My script:

```
data = data_df.values.tolist()
sql = "insert into %s(%s) values(%s)" %(table_name, cols, values)
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
```

I have tried the solution given by the cx-Oracle documentation(https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.3/user_guide/sql_execution.html#inserting-nulls). But it returned this error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-04043: object SDO_GEOMETRY does not exist
```

Because it's in production environment, that I can't do anything to oracle's settings. Is there any solution that can I insert null value into the oracle table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example reproducing your problem

```
d  = {'id': [1, pd.NA], 'col': [ pd.NA,'x' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df.values.tolist())
cur.executemany("insert into tab(id, col) values (:1, :2)", df.values.tolist()) 

[[1, <NA>], [<NA>, 'x']]
...
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type NAType not supported.
```

Note that the table definition is as follows

```
 create table tab(id int, col varchar2(10));
```

The error appears while insering the NA in a  `VARCHAR2` column - would it be a *number* column, you'll observe
`TypeError: expecting number`

The solution is to remove the  `NA` and to replace them with `None`

```
df.loc[0,'col'] = None
df.loc[1,'id'] = None
```

The data now looks as follows and the `insert` works fine

```
[[1, None], [None, 'x']]
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really the problem that NA can't insert into a VARCHAR2 column. At first I use "df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)" to replace NA to None, but it didn't work. I solved it by "df.fillna('')",  and set the oracle table's columns-datatype to VARCHAR2.

Comment: Yes, @yyding `fillna` with empty string works for character columns, though I did not manage an equivalent for `NUMBER` columns.

Comment: Only the following numbers can be stored in an oracle `NUMBER` column: _(1)Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10-130 to 9.99...9 x 10125 with up to 38 significant digits_; _(2)Negative numbers from -1 x 10-130 to 9.99...99 x 10125 with up to 38 significant digits_; _(3)Zero_; _(4)Positive and negative infinity (generated only by importing from an Oracle Database, Version_. So you can't store an None values in it. You may try delete the row which with `NA` or replace the `NA` to zero or others as you need.

Comment: You may store `null` in a `number` column which is demonstrated in the example above (column `id`) @yyding

Comment: Yes, it may store a `NULL` value in oracle when I insert a python `None` in the `NUMBER` column. Thank you. And I am ashamed of myself that I didn't look at all the contents of the example carefully.